# Redis number of dbs

Tags: redis

I have redis 3.0 running on my Centos 6.6. I've set number of `databases` to `128` in `redis.conf` file. I've restarted redis after config change.

When I do: `SELECT 16` it still returns following error: `(error) ERR invalid DB index`

What I am doing wrong here, how to I increase number of dbs in redis?

Comment: do you use the correct redis.conf or do you connect the correct redis-server?

Comment: Also note that numbered databases are not supported if you're using the cluster mode